# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' can be called with these arguments

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

I have a dataset in ssrs in which one of the parameter has expression as

```
=IIF(Parameters!EquipmentTypeID.Value(0)=-1,NOTHING,JOIN(CInt(Split(Parameters!EquipmentTypeID.Value," ").GetValue(0)),","))
```

'Parameters!EquipmentTypeID.Value' has value in the form like **'38 612-FTQ-> Wheels'** from which I want to extract 38 in my expression.

But when I run the report, I get following error:

Overload resolution failed becuase no accessible 'Join' can be called with these arguments.
[image: Error]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `JOIN` function do you think you're calling? You're passing an `Integer` and a `String` to it and, according to the error message, there is no such function. Work out what function you're trying to call and what it expects as arguments and then pass arguments of that type.

Comment: How about you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, instead of expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't do it? Joining anything generally involves at least two things and yet you have one number, so what good can possibly come out of that?

Comment: @user18387401 ' Join' Returns a string created by joining a number of substrings contained in an array.

Comment: @user18387401 The expression will return the first two characters of the parameter and also the parameter equipment type is a multivalue parameter. So I want concatenation of all the numbers extracted form parameter. eg - 38,41,34,35.....

Comment: I know what it does. Do you? Read your own words: "a number of substrings contained in an array". Now read your own code. Are you passing an array containing a number of substrings? Did you read the error message that tells you that you're not?

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide all the relevant information that you should have in the first place.

Comment: @user18387401 How do I make array of the parameter?

Comment: Why would you want to make an array of one number for the express purpose of joining it at all? What do you think you're joining it to?

Comment: @user18387401 That's what I am not able to figure out. I just want numbers in form 38,35,34,32 where each number is returned from parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do what you are attempting to do using JOIN as it expects an array so even trying to join `LEFT(Parameters!EquipmentTypeID.Value, 2)` would not work.

You might want to consider a custom function to handle this or even do it in the database.

You could create a dataset that returns this value something like this.

```
-- assumes a table called myTableWithEquipmentTypeIDs with a columne called EquipmentTypeID
declare @result nvarchar(1000) = ''

SELECT @result = @result
                 + CASE @result WHEN '' then '' ELSE ', ' END 
                 + e
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT left(EquipmentTypeID, 2) as e 
                    FROM myTableWithEquipmentTypeIDs
                    WHERE EquipmentTypeID IN (@EquipmentTypeID)
                    ) a

SELECT @result as myResult
```

Then all you have to do to reference this result is set the textbox expression to `=FIRST(Fields!myResult.Value, "myDataSetName")`